# TypeScript: Is it possible to mix a static property of one class with another class without using inheritance or implementation of interface?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, static

I'd like that Intellisense of TypeScript recognize a `static` property inherited through a `interface`, without apply inheritance or implementation in a concrete class. Is it possible?

```js
interface Interface2 {

    instancePropertyRecognizedByInterfaceInheritance: string;

}

class Interface1 {

    constructor() {

    }

    instanceMethodRecognizedByInterfaceInheritance(): void {

    }

}

class InheritsFromAll {

    static inheritedClassProperty: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;

}

// interfaces permit multiple inheritance even from another class
interface InheritsFromAll extends 
    Interface1,
    Interface2
    {

}

// it works only for instance properties
interface MixedClass extends InheritsFromAll {

}

class MixedClass {
    
}

const mixedClass: MixedClass = new MixedClass();

// recognized
mixedClass.instanceMethodRecognizedByInterfaceInheritance();

// not recognized
MixedClass.inheritedClassProperty;
```

Comment: What is `newClassProperty`?  A typo?

Comment: Looks like you want [ms/TS#2957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2957) to allow easy declaration merging for the static side of a class.  For now there are only workarounds like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqQaQm).  I will write up an answer explaining this unless I'm missing something about your question.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I edited, the correct is `inheritedClassProperty`

Comment: @jcalz this isn't exactly what I want. I want to not need to re-declare a static property already previously written in TypeScript.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, but you cannot merge into the static side of a class the way you can for the instance side. As I said, there are only workarounds. A different workaround: since `MixedClass` as you defined will not actually have those static or instance properties, you can suppress the entire JS output and do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3ak3w).  The "inheritance" has no effect on anything at runtime. If you need something like `class MixedClass {}` in your TS code, could you show it in your [mre]?

Comment: In any case, do you want an answer that just says "no, sorry, go to [ms/TS#2957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2957) and give it a  if you want, but this is impossible"... or do you want suggestions for workarounds as well?

Comment: Workarounds too. Imagine a class with many `static` methods or `static` properties, I'd have to re-declare all in a `module` or a `namespace` to just the TypeScript compiler. I would have to declare them all just for the TypeScript to recognize them and allow the build to proceed. This is ridiculous. All this because TypeScript does not support `static` declarations in `interfaces`, otherwise it would normally allow their inheritance, saving me unnecessary headaches.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the use case.  I can imagine a class with many static properties, but I don't understand why you need to merge those into something instead of using inheritance. Can you demonstrate a toy use case that motivates this as a [mre]? Your frustration is noted but I don't know how to help with that; at best I can point to GitHub issues that help explain why things are the way they are (e.g., [this comment](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892#issuecomment-542440546) which mentions why `static` things in `interface`s are problematic).

Comment: Yes. My bad. It's to mixing through decorators. See [that example](https://tsplay.dev/mixing-through-decorators), please.

Comment: There's a *lot* to unpack in that example. `instancePropertyRecognizedThroughInterfaceInheritance` doesn't exist and leads to runtime errors. I don't understand why someone would want instance properties from some instance to be copied the prototype of the mixed class. I would love to see a *minimal* example here where all you're doing is some stuff with static properties, since that's what you're asking about. Decorators are an experimental feature anyway, so they are best avoided. You can mix statics [like this](//tsplay.dev/wX258m), does that work for you?

Comment: Please, ignore `instancePropertyRecognizedThroughInterfaceInheritance`, this was just an intellisense test, and ignore the `export` statements too.
Yes, it works for me.

There is no concrete project where I want to apply this code, I just wanted to generically implement the same behavior that `PHP traits` do.

Comment: @jcalz just one more thing. Is it possible to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX258m) with an arbitrary number of parameters?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wg6j0W) maybe? Issues surrounding variadics are probably out of scope for the question as asked so in my answer I will focus on just the one-arg version (nothing stops you from writing `MixStatics(Class2, MixStatics(Class1, class MixedClass { /*...*/ }))`, it's just uglier)

Comment: @jcalz fantastic. I don't even know how to thank you. But about the syntax, I don't understand two things: why `(x: T[K]) => void` istead just `T[K]`, and why `{...}[number] extends ...`, I mean `{...}[number]`???

Comment: The answer to those has to do with conditional type inference and contravariance to infer intersections, and mapping over tuples and then getting the union of their element types by indexing with `number`. I don't know how much to go into in this already very long comment chain. I think the next thing I do here will be to write up the answer to the original question, and if you still have followup questions you might want to post them as new posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, there is currently no way to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to modify the static side of a class.  There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#2957](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2957) asking for a way to do this, but for the foreseeable future, there are only workarounds.  The one mentioned in that issue is to declare a `namespace`/`module` with the same name as the class constructor, and `export` statics individually:

```
namespace MixedClass {
  export const inheritedClassProperty = InheritsFromAll.inheritedClassProperty;
}
const mixedClass: MixedClass = new MixedClass();

MixedClass.inheritedClassProperty;
```

For some people, that works well enough for their use cases.

---

If it doesn't work for you, the best approach would be to step back and try to think of the underlying use case and whether or not there is a solution that doesn't involve declaration merging at all.  If you just want to use the statics of one class as a mixin for another class, you can maybe make a function which takes both the mixin and the target class constructor and returns the target class constructor as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of both the original constructor and the static part of the mixin constructor, like this:

```
const MixStatics = <T, U>(mixin: T, ctor: U) => Object.assign(ctor, mixin) as
    U & { [K in keyof T as Exclude<K, "prototype">]: T[K] };
```

This produces a type like `U & T`, where `U` is the type of the target class constructor `ctor`, and `T` is the type of the `mixin` statics.  But we don't want to copy the `prototype` property or the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) from `T` into the output, since [the `Object.assign()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) won't copy those.  Hence the [key-remapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

Let's test it out:

```
class StaticsToMixIn {
    static staticProp: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;
    static prop1 = 1;
    static prop2 = 2;
    /*..*/
    static prop100 = 100;
}

const MixedClass = MixStatics(StaticsToMixIn, class MixedClass {
    static anotherStaticProp: string = `class property defined in ${this.name}`;
});

/* const MixedClass: typeof MixedClass & {
    staticProp: string;
    prop1: number;
    prop2: number;
    prop100: number;
} */

type MixedClass = InstanceType<typeof MixedClass>
```

According to the compiler, `MixedClass` is a class constructor of the same type as the class expression passed as the second argument of `MixStatics`, as well as an object type containing all the statics from `StaticsToMixin`.

And things seem to work similarly at runtime:

```
console.log(MixedClass.staticProp) // "class property defined in StaticsToMixIn" 
console.log(MixedClass.prop1) // 1
console.log(MixedClass.prop2) // 2
/*..*/
console.log(MixedClass.prop100) // 100
console.log(MixedClass.anotherStaticProp); // "class property defined in MixedClass"
```

---

Is `MixStatics()` perfect?  Probably not; there are likely many edge cases when you copy things from one constructor to another, both at runtime and in the type system.  But at least this has the potential to programmatically merge the static side of classes together in a way that declaration merging currently cannot.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAICyBLAHgZVgQ1s014BeeAHgBUAaeAVQD4AKAWzWUgC55L5RZwAnDtQCURWvADyAIwBWAUx4A6LNGjIA5pHo9+VZqlYjlweCZrwAZPADe8ANoBpeK3gBrWQE9wAM07xl8AFFUUAAbAFcAE1kSeyoAIgAHPnBeWHcE2TjaAF0OMgds+ABfAG4QUOUCTBw8aDJwFFQASUhrY1M4GtB4TtxQAAVkhI44PlY1IngAAwqVeCTwDL40+CivVlkIp1aAEitYAAtkaAVILEZZIqmy0x7sPvmhgEZJp5uO+7xHxYAmSZ-3iYAPQAKgUChBQPaJl6XwWCSeAAZEa9kWUiuUoHAkGhNgBhEKVSaNap9aD0Um1eqNFpUWYERr4wlzKzQu5dPyQFIHWR8SkDIYjWBjSATYgzZkEeG8lZrDZbZx7Q7HU7nS7XYBFIRlYCg7hYhCMiIEyocNIZbw41BMomWVm3WECxZCkVqQHfBEcSBhRiSXnu+E-L0+v18APPZHB33+zXwSEgc2yK02ubEFqdSCgWRkdLRROWo0mlS0TEwcAhWQKELgNT0QuShSOwaLERAoHwOL0j0y9yrWTrSCbbbwfl1BpoFpxeBgLHlyvV2v1yoKeFPVvtp4zssVqs1uu440NwPr+A-XVgiFQiDb+d7pcqFcRxEnpGIrfQOe7xcHosnLBcw5eX5ZsEm1eA2w7LtpWWXs5UHBVWnvaApxAYAzguaAEiwLN4AAdX4FwsGSMJIC2Vk2VYWBeS8bCkxaKi+BorM-ntW5TFYDMsxAnsACV5BrSBkAAL02AAhdx6Oo2iWh5MZsEzWQXXGd0MTZLtJMY2iXlYtj9RgYUwm0Ph6BEGwMV0kwOPkrNEFkQ5wAiPiIA0YSxIkyAGKY2QZN5ZBrNkEyOAAN3AZAyOKNlVNudTIFkvzoAAMWSRgAEEQhCNoLPZB5WDiqjD0qbiYKU0VJglIloNlft5WHJUjhOdD1RUkBbggyipKzKVeWYBBGDCEJcASCttjy-8cNkILZFaLxks5bleW4SUKI8jq6Ni3zYES5K0oy2RUCo0iCA0rynioY7aJYiK2TahAAHcCIIKAQl7Lx+G2Tik0q5BZGgZbPNo5MCrmPaDoiI71rkrbwFS9LrCu6LJUB384ai0wIM8MJuH-ONGH-MIsHS9wQT8CItiiCo+BqLFtgiZAgrC-HCfgXhmZ5bKvlUKJ4EtLBFqJenecazCAb2hJ+Fga722gWQkwOWBYASaA2DbNQ-IOMJJAUCBGCBZhQGSD8vFgIEcwydB9eQBJjeOaAwh+oEfgATgAVgAdmnW4hawnCkMyizRfFvTsVyjaU2gIqVjTCH4qS6GdoUEO5LDiP3Ga6KDXgPQw44X3iEHW6kclEydVa9s+H4lyRIiNks6Bk4rLG2RbPsxyK8EqvxPOrMfLkxvi5atGy7b1zq9uJCE+j-LfxTnUiiAA)

Comment: Thanks. I understood about contravariance after read [that](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) documentation. The `{}[number]` returns the union ((arg2CompareSign: typeof C1) => void | (arg2CompareSign: typeof C2) => void | ...). This functions are mapped through `Mapped Types`. When we use an union with the statement "extends" combined with `ternary operator`, we are telling TypeScript that we want to remap the elements of this union. The statement "extends" doesn't inherit in this cases, but compare types.